# Get data in daterange plus first date before and after this daterange in elasticsearch

Tags: database, elasticsearch, date-range

I am quite new to elasticsearch and I am impressed by all the functionality it offers. Now I have a special case, where I am not sure if elasticsearch will be able to handle it.

Overall I am searching for a type within a daterange.
But in addition I need the first date before and after this daterange as well.
I do not know how far these dates are away, so I can not just add a specific amount of days to the daterange.

I know this would be possible with 3 different queries, but would it be possible in just one query as well?

Any ideas?

Edit (example):

```
[uuid1] = [
    ['id' => 1, 'date' => '1970/01/01 12:00:00', 'val' => 'ages ago'],
    ['id' => 2, 'date' => '2010/01/01 12:00:00', 'val' => 'randomValueSomewhereInThePast'],
    ['id' => 3, 'date' => '2017/01/03 12:00:00', 'val' => 'valueInTimeRange3'],
    ['id' => 4, 'date' => '2017/01/04 12:00:00', 'val' => 'valueInTimeRange4'],
    ['id' => 5, 'date' => '2017/01/05 12:00:00', 'val' => 'valueInTimeRange5'],
    ['id' => 6, 'date' => '2017/01/06 12:00:00', 'val' => 'valueInTimeRange6'],
    ['id' => 7, 'date' => '2020/01/05 12:00:00', 'val' => 'randomValueSomewhereInTheFuture']
    ['id' => 8, 'date' => '9999/01/05 12:00:00', 'val' => 'wayTooFarAway']
]
```

As you can see I got several dates. Now I have a given DateRange from

```
2017/01/03 12:00:00 to 2017/01/06 12:00:00
```

So a simple request with range would return me values 3,4,5,6.
But I need values 2 & 7 aswell. 
These are the dates right before and right after my range. I do not know when they are so I can not just adjust the rang.

Comment: Could you give some example with sample data with an id field and date field?

Comment: added an example. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to get some close dates after ranging exact values?